# How to use back references at addresses with extended regular expressions in sed in macOS

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'd like to use back references at addresses with extended regular expressions in `sed` in macOS (version 12.4).

With basic regular expressions, I can use back references (that is, this is an expected result):

```
% echo -e 'Foo,Foo\nFoo,Bar' | sed '/\(Foo\),\1/s//__SAME__/'
__SAME__
Foo,Bar
```

However, with extended regular expressions, the following back reference does not work:

```
% echo -e 'Foo,Foo\nFoo,Bar' | sed -E '/(Foo),\1/s//__SAME__/'
Foo,Foo
Foo,Bar
```

Can I use back references at addresses with extended regular expressions with some modifications?

The difference in back references between basic and extended regular expressions seems odd. Is this a bug?

For your information, both of the above commands work well with GNU sed 4.8.

Comment: This is most likely a bug in BSD sed. It works fine with `gnu sed` using `-E`

Comment: On OSX use: `perl -pe 's/(Foo),\1/__SAME__/' file`

Comment: To improve my question, I would appreciate comments about the reasons for the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [regular-expressions.info "*POSIX Extended Regular Expressions*"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), the

> **The POSIX standard does not define [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)**. Some implementations do support `\1` through `\9`, but **these are not part of the standard for ERE**. ERE is an extension of the old UNIX grep, not of POSIX BRE.

Hence, a Perl alternative here is quite a viable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

As mentioned in my comments above that BSD `sed` in ERE mode doesn't support back-references like `\1`. Wiktor has also attached a reference that states clearly that POSIX standard doesn't support it.

As I commented above a better alternative would be to use `perl` like this:

```
perl -pe 's/(Foo),\1/__SAME__/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e ',s/\\(Foo\\),\\1/__SAME__/\nwq' | ed -s file -
```

This pipes ed commands into an invocation of ed and amends `file`.

N.B. I don't use MacOs but according to its manual it uses FreeBSD which accomodates back references in standard unix editor ed.